# In divisor algorithm for integers, why the divisor needs to be positive?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

In the introductory abstract algebra texts, the division algorithm for integers read:
For any a, b ∈ **Z** and b > 0, there exist a unique q, r ∈ **Z** where 0 ≤ r <b such that a = bq + r.

Now my question is, why the divisor b is limited to positive integers? For the remainder r, it makes sense from the modular arithmetic point of view. But why the divisor? **Z**/b**Z** for any b < 0 can be similarly defined as for any b > 0. Only if we define so, we'll find that **Z**/-b**Z** = **Z**/b**Z** for all b ≠ 0 ∈ **Z**. So, it only makes sense to talk about **Z**/|b|**Z**. So why not change the requirement for b, the divisor of the division algorithm to b ≠ 0 and for the remainder to 0 ≤ r <|b|?

Comment: I beg pardon for my juvenile question in advance. One possible answer to my question is that the division algorithm appears quite early in the textbook. So authors probably pose this cosmetic limitation just to make things easy and leave this insignificant expansion to eager readers. But is that all or is there a theoretical necessity too?

Comment: "So why not change the requirement for b, the divisor of the division algorithm to b ≠ 0 and for the remainder to 0 ≤ r <|b|?"  No reason at all.  But... there isn't a good reason to  either.  And ... later... when we are concerned with modular arithmetic and divisibility... negative values just won't be important or interesting and making exceptions for them will be .... irritating.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think all textbooks restrict the divisor to be positive.

[image: Division Algo]

The abovementioned screenshot is from my book named "Fundamentals of Abstract Algebra" and it does not have restriction you said you don't understand why.

Since one can prove the statement with no restriction, there should not be any notable theoretical necessity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. And also for this wonderful book.

Comment: You're welcome.